# Функция copyfile() в mac os возвращает ошибку "Not a directory"

Tags: c++, macos, mac, файлы, apple

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые форумчане!
Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться в том, как работает функция. Почитала документацию на Apple Developer, да там столько всего, что глаза разбегаются, и не понятно, куда что передавать и где как что вызывается.
Адрес документации: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/copyfile.3.html

А вот код, который у меня получился, однако, сколько я не пробовала менять передаваемые флаги, она почему-то всегда возвращает -1, что согласно документации означает ошибку. Файл действительно не копируется.

```
string path = "/Users/user-name/Documents/My.app";
char destination[] = {"/Applications/My.app"};

copyfile_state_t state = copyfile_state_alloc();
int err = copyfile(path.c_str(), destination, state,  COPYFILE_RECURSIVE);
copyfile_state_free(state);
```

Answer (score 1):

Видимо нужны права суперпользователя.

**Обновление**

Ну тогда не будем гадать. Подобные функции выставляют специальный флаг в переменной errno. Ее значение можно распечатать (это целочисленная переменная). А можно и декодировать в строку функцией strerror. А там будет понятнее.

Comment: @KoVadim, при ручном копировании в папку Applications система не просит ввести ничего, значит и программно можно положить туда файл. Когда пробовала через терминал копировать, файл спокойно копировался в папку.

Comment: Исправила код на такой:  
  
    string path = "/Users/user-name/Documents/My.app";
    char destination[] = {"/Applications/My.app"};
    
    copyfile_state_t state = copyfile_state_alloc();
    copyfile_state_set(state, COPYFILE_STATE_SRC_FD, path.c_str());
    
    err = copyfile(NULL, destination, state, COPYFILE_RECURSE_FILE);
    if(err < 0)
    {
        cout << errno << endl;
        cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
    }
    copyfile_state_free(state);
  
Теперь файл копируется, но когда я пытаюсь его открыть, система пишет, что у меня недостаточно прав на это, и не открывает...(((

Comment: Классическое `ls -al /Applications/My.app`, и смотрите на права доступа.

Comment: @KoVadim, Права доступа staff, я же могу запустить приложение до копирования. Значит, данный пользователь и скопировать его может, потому что пробовала удалять и добавлять файлы в папку приложения.

Comment: staff - это пользователь. А права обычно выглядят как `-rwx---r--`.